# cloth rig problem

Tags: rigify

whenever I move the legs the clothes moves different what I saw I try weight painting but still it is moving creepy way I try a lot for example assign some vertices so that it prevent from moving but it is still moving.
the character use a generate rig and I can't weight paint the generate rig it doesn't follow the way I paint no matter what i just want to prevent the way the the cloth is moving.
[image]

as you can see in this picture when I move the leg up the upper part of the pants move I need it to stay.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer their was in the properties panel in object data that have the shape like a human shape the a check box
[image]

this one let me see the armature the can be weight painting and now it work thx a lot.